# Assign custom scores to clauses in boolean query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring, booleanquery

In Elasticsearch I am testing the following query:

```
GET sdata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "f1": "sth" } }
      ],
      "should": [
        { "match": { "f2": "sth" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I know that the overall score of retrieved documents depends on the number of matches they achieve. but is it possible to customize the final score so that the documents that match the `should` clause may be weighted much more higher than documents that match the `must` alone? can I add a script to determine how each clause contribute to the final score?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`boost`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) parameter along with the `should` clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "f1": "sth"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "f2": {
              "query": "sth",
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```